# Why the figure is not in one column only?

Tags: floats

I have the following code. Why is my figure partially in one column and then also going off the page? How do I make it single column?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newspaper}
\usepackage{float}


\date{\today}
\currentvolume{1}
\currentissue{3}

%% [LianTze] The newspaper package also provides 
%% these commands to set various metadata:

%% The banner headline on the first page
%%   (The colon after s: is to get a more
%%   modern majuscule s in this font instead of 
%%   the medieval tall s. For anyone interested 
%%   in the history: 
%%  http://medievalwriting.50megs.com/scripts/letters/historys.htm)
\SetPaperName{The Report}

%% The name used in the running header after
%% the first page
\SetHeaderName{The Report}

%% and also...
\SetPaperLocation{\raisebox{-0.5\height}}
\SetPaperSlogan{``example''}
\SetPaperPrice{4\%}

% [LianTze] times (the package not the font) is rather outdated now; use newtx (see later)
% \usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{picinpar}
%uasage of picinpar:
%\begin{window}[1,l,\includegraphics{},caption]xxxxx\end{window}


%% [LianTze] Contains some modifications
\usepackage{newspaper-mod}
%%... so now you can redefine the headline and byline style if you want to.
%% These can be issued just before any
%% byline or headline in the paper, to
%% individually style each article
%%
% \renewcommand{\headlinestyle}{\itshape\Large\lsstyle}
% \renewcommand{\bylinestyle}{\bfseries\Large\raggedright}

%%%%%%%%%  Front matter   %%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2}

\byline{Abstract}{A.D}

\lipsum[1-3]   

\headline{ex}

\begin{figure}[H]
\includegraphics{ex.png}
\caption{picture}

\end{figure}

\closearticle

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you have included the image without scaling it at all so if it is wider than the column width then it will overprint the other column. (We can not run the example to see the problem). `\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{..}` perhaps?

Comment: Your code is not compileable : `LaTeX Error: File "newspaper-mod.sty" not found.`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks this worked!